# Google Doesn't take my directed image, it Takes suitable image for google plus share

Tags: google-plus

According to google developers platform https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet
there are three ways to share information on google plus. I'm using open graph for sharing contents on social platform and the codes are as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Hepimiz aynı Allah'a mı inanıyoruz?-NİHAT HATİPOĞLU-Sabah" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Hepimiz aynı Allah'a mı inanıyoruz?" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i.sabah.com.tr/sbh/y/99ac7dac-f10f-49ec-800c-03c1d038bdd1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />

<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.sabah.com.tr/Yazarlar/hatipoglu/2014/05/16/hepimiz-ayni-allaha-mi-inaniyoruz?qwert=1" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="sabah.com.tr" />
```

The problem is google doesn't take image that I wrote in og:image tag. It takes suitable image on the page. I also tried other ways to see correct image but unfortunately I couldn't achieve to show correct image. So, what should I do to share correct image ?

Answer (score 1):

Schema.org markup is preferred on Google+. Use the snippet tool to configure your content:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet